# Identify clicked p:commandButton in actionListener method

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, identifier, commandbutton

I'm tyring to get clicked button id in the action listener method.

This is my xhtml code:

```
<p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Delete" action="#{student.xxx()}"
                 actionListener="#{student.UserActionListener(e)}"/>
```

This is my function for event handling in which I want to get id of a clicked button:

```
public void  UserActionListener (ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("the button id");
}
```

How is it possible to obtain id of submit button in action listener method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.getComponent()

```
.......
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class ........{

    public String buttonId; 

    public void  UserActionListener (ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClientId());

    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know button id it will be auto generated so i whant to get id not button name

Comment: He meant to say `get("id")`

Comment: @gknicker actually it has no getComponent() method , i've missed something?

Comment: Try this - event.getComponent().getParent().getId()

Comment: @Ranish event does not have function like getComponent()

Comment: @Gtopuria perhaps you wanted to import [`javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ActionEvent.html) instead of whatever ActionEvent class you're importing (possibly [`java.awt.event.ActionEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html)?)

Comment: .......
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
 
public class ........{
 
 public String buttonId; 
 
 public void  UserActionListener (ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getComponent().getClientId());

    }
}

Comment: Please clean up your answer to post an actually tested/working answer instead of a bunch of "try this" shoot-in-the-darks. Then I'll remove the downvote. You'll get an additional upvote if you point out another severe mistake in XHTML side in the question's code.

Comment: @BalusC I almost finished rewriting this answer as I stumbled upon your comment after what the edit has been discarded. You're right, the answerer should do that job on his own.

Comment: @BalusC answer edited and has the working solution which worked out for Gtopuria